# How to extend existing paypal with adaptive payment?

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal

i am having small doubt in PHP development.

Now i am using PayPal payment for products cart in my WordPress website.

that payment can be send to one partner.

now i want to split all payments to two PayPal partners.

for example product price 10$

then

user1=8$

user2=2$

if there any possibility available to this development. Every payment will be split into two partners. all payment will be split to into two partners.
if any having idea or sample code then give. it may be use full for me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a feature available for this. Its called "[Adaptive Payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)".

`The Adaptive Payments API allows merchants and developers to pay almost anyone and set up automated payments. They can create applications that manage payments, payment preapprovals, and refunds. They can also send money peer-to-peer, split payments in both parallel and chained models, accept guest payments, and schedule disbursements. The Adaptive Payments API works on multiple platforms including the web and mobile environments.`

Sample API Request :Eg : [Parallel Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-parallelPayment-curl-etc/)

```
actionType=PAY      #The action taken in the Pay request (that is, the PAY action)
&clientDetails.applicationId=APP-80W284485P519543T #Standard Sandbox App ID
&clientDetails.ipAddress=127.0.0.1     #Address from which request is sent  
&senderEmail=sender_email
&currencyCode=USD       #The currency, e.g. US dollars
&receiverList.receiver(0).amount=3.00     #The payment amount for the first receiver 
&receiverList.receiver(0).email=first_receiver_email
&receiverList.receiver(1).amount=4.00   #The payment amount for the second receiver 
&receiverList.receiver(1).email=second_receiver_email
&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US
&returnUrl=http://www.yourdomain.com/success.html   #For use if the consumer proceeds with payment
&cancelUrl=http://www.yourdomain.com/cancel.html    #For use if the consumer decides not to proceed with payment
```

Sample Codes in [github](https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php)

Comment: yes i got this documentation. can you have a sample API for that issue